# The preimage of a curve in the projective plane by the quotient map.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $q:S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$ the quotient map between the $n$-sphere and the $n$-dimensional projective plane. Prove that if $\alpha$ is a curve in the projective plane then $p^{-1}\alpha$ is a closed curve or the union of two disjoint closed curves.

I am almost done.

Let $[x]\in\mathbb{R}P^n $. Since $q$ is a covering map there exists a unique elevation $\bar\alpha$ such that $\bar\alpha(0)=x\in[x]$ this implies that the other curve is $-\bar\alpha(t)$ (the one that begins in $-x$). This give a description of all the possible elevations for the point $[x]$.

Here we have two options:
First one: $\bar\alpha(0)=-\bar\alpha(1)$.
This implies that $\alpha *-\alpha$ is a closed curve.

Second one: $\bar\alpha(0)=\bar\alpha(1)$.
This implies that $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ are closed curve.

Why is it that these curves are necessarily disjoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to say that $\alpha$ is a *closed* curve?

Comment: Yes a mean a closed curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't have to be disjoint, actually. One can construct a counter example as follows. Take a closed curve $c$ on $S^n$, such that $c\neq-c$, but $c\cap-c\neq\emptyset$ (there's no problem doing that). Project $c$ (or $-c$) to the projective space, and you're done.

**Edit:** If the initial curve $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is *simple*, and its preimage consists of two curves, then these two curves are necessarily disjoint. Otherwise, each one of them contains a pair of antipodal points, and this means self intersection downstairs.

Comment: And if the curve is simple?

Comment: @YotasTrejos Please see the edit.